# How to escape " in sed on Windows?

Tags: windows, sed, escaping

I want to replace all the `,` characters in a file with `,"` using sed (Windows/cmd). This is what I've tried:

```
>head -n3 SiteRank.csv
1,facebook.com
2,google.com
3,youtube.com

>head -n3 SiteRank.csv | sed s/,/,"/
1,facebook.com
2,google.com
3,youtube.com

>head -n3 SiteRank.csv | sed s/,/,\"/
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

>head -n3 SiteRank.csv | sed s/,/,\\"/
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

>head -n3 SiteRank.csv | sed s/,/,^"/
1,facebook.com
2,google.com
3,youtube.com
```

Comment: What about quoting the sed script?  `head -n3 SiteRank.csv | sed 's/,/,"/'`

Comment: Also, is your real goal to place quotes around the second field in this CSV?  Best to avoid [XY problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  Tell us what you're REALLY trying to do.

Comment: @ghoti - yeah, I want to try to quote the second variable, I figured once I know how to fix the quotes the rest will be easy.

Comment: @ghoti - thanks for the solution btw (I posted it as an answer, it works!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to my X problem (I actually publisehd a Y problem, see `ghoti`'s helpful comments)

```
head -n3 SiteRank.csv | sed 's/,/,^"/' | sed 's/$/^"/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
head -n3 SiteRank.csv | sed 's/,\|$/&"/g'
```

or if there might be more than one `,`:

```
head -n3 SiteRank.csv | sed 's/,\(.*\)/,"\1"/'
```

Comment: Windows has never supported `'` as quoting of command line arguments.